# If app opens from splash screen it crash?

Tags: ios, flutter, mobile

I have a problem. I have an application written in flutter which collects locations and motion activities. I have some problems while using it. I have it running in the background. Sometimes when I open it I see a splash screen. It looks like the application has crash, but I do not have any log in firebase. In application logs I can only see that main function was called again. Is it system killed my application? If so, how can I confirm it?

Comment: Can you include [minimal-reproducible-example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)